# SQL Server 2014 - Reset everything

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Short of reinstalling the software, is there a simple way to 'start from scratch' with a SQL instance? By that I mean:

- Remove all created logons,
- Remove all added databases,
- Reset system databases,
- Remove any new configuration,
- Reset any SQL Server Agent configuration

I can't find anything online on how to do this.

Answer (score 14):

You should [rebuild the system databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx).

```
Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts [ /SAPWD= StrongPassword ] [ /SQLCOLLATION=CollationName]
```

This would not remove the data and log files relating to the old databases - it just removes all references to them. You would have to manually remove the files to free up the disk space.

You must also install all service packs and hotfixes again.